# How to get contents of deployed ESQL File using IBM Integration Bus API

Tags: java, messagebroker

For a project I want to get the contents of a deployed ESQL file using the IBM API in my own Java program.
I can get the EG's, Applications and Message Flows without any problems (all called Proxy at the end). I can also list the nodes in a Message Flow, such as ComputeNodes. I cannot find, however, which ESQL Module a ComputeNode uses; this is a property not present in the properties list. Furthermore, I would like to find this deployed module and see its contents. There seems to be no ESQLProxy or something.
Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. its possible

**mqsireportproperties BROKERNAME -e  EGNAME -o AllMessageFlows -r > EGcode**

But it will give all deployed flows ESQLcode in that particular EG.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm looking to use the API and get the information in my Java program. I'm not using the commandline.

Comment: Why do you want to extract the deployed ESQL? ( what's the business objective )?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.
There is certain information in the ESQL I need, such as (hardcoded) DB-references and Id's I want to extract.